Keyboard icon in the menu bar shows letter A
For some reason, the first language of the keyboard icon in the menu bar shows the letter A. I know this is supposed to be NL  like it was on my previous laptop. I have no idea why it shows the letter A and how to fix it. Any ideas?


I think it basically stands for your first and default input method. If you set American ABC as default it will become NL.

If you have only one Latin keyboard active, I think the icon becomes A.

I mean, that's just incomprehensible. Why would you want an icon that doesn't indicate the language you're using? I don't get this decision by Apple.
